# Reading an xls in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read an xls file in the column format:

```
File Name    File Size
Hello           45
World           11
```

I want to read all the first name column entries as a list of strings and all the file size column entries as a list of ints. How can i do this? I have the following code:

```
    OleDbDataReader reader;
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + xlsFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]", con);

    con.Open();
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? You could use the office interop APIs.

Comment: I would really like to stick to the above method and yes i am using VS2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select [File Size] from [sheet1$]", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't ask about this, but the OLEDB driver for Excel, etc. won't work in 64 bit without jumping thru kludgey hoops. It's likely your app will need to run on a 64-bit machine if it doesn't already. I have had a lot of luck with www.spreadsheetgear.com. 64-bit capable and very easy to use API for manipulating Excel.

No affiliation, just a happy customer.